# PostgreSQL libpq PGconnectdb

Tags: postgresql, libpq

in Postgresql I create a db like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDatabase;
```

Since is unquoted, it is actually created like this `testdatabase`

And I am fine with that.

The problem is that if I use libpq.PQconnectdb in the form

```
PGconn *PQconnectdb(const char *conninfo);
```

If I compose the dababase name part of the conninfo like this:

```
dbName=TestDatabase
```

I would expect that, as being not quoted, the name is turned to lowercase and therefore the connection is actually done to testdatabase, and therefore succeds, but this is not the case:

> PostgreSQL: FATAL:  database "TestDatabase" does not exist

I use PostgreSQL server 13 on a debian 11.5 system.

Any suggestion?

Comment: If the question is whether you should **1. quote outside of libpq** or **2. use lowercase in libpq** - it's entirely up to your setup and what you'll find more comfortable. I think that defaulting to quoted notation is fairly common in client libraries and ORMs.

Comment: So you already know what the problem is and what the solution is.  My suggestion would be to do the thing that works, rather than the thing that doesn't.

Comment: The reason why I was asking is that the need of create with unquoted camel case, knowing that it will be created lower case, and asking for a connection in lowercase means that I have to transfer to the client application the knowledge that RDBMS works in this way. And this is not equally true for all RDBMS (for example PostgreSQL vs SQLite).